# Yellow Needle Problem

Tags: mathematics

Suppose there exists an infinite number of equally spaced parallel green, yellow, red and blue lines, and we were to randomly toss a yellow colored needle whose length is less than or equal to the distance between adjacent lines. What is the probability that the needle will cross a yellow line?

Comment: sounds like a math problem ([Buffon's needle problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuffonsNeedleProblem.html)) for me. maybe even homework?

Comment: Yes, elias, it's a variation of the Buffon's Needle Problem. It's not homework.

Answer (score 3):

This is [Buffon's Needle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuffonsNeedleProblem.html) problem with $d=4l$ (from Mathworld).

so the probability is $\dfrac{1}{2\pi}$.